# Create 'Time' from 'Datetime' to compare event time from different days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

**Summary**
I have a csv file as a datasource which I am loading into a pandas dataframe.
It contains a column for datetime including timestamp and spans a history of multiple months, automatically created when someone performs different scanning actions with a machine. The type of action is also recorded in a seperate column:

| Index | Datetime | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12/7/2021 16:39:46 | a |
| 1 | 16/6/2021 10:24:26 | a |
| 2 | 21/6/2021 12:43:35 | b |
| 3 | 11/6/2021 19:56:28 | a |
| 4 | 28/5/2021 14:28:47 | b |

**Problem**
To plot a type of heatmap and find out when over the day actions are clustered, I wanted to isolate the timestamp from the Datetime, because I don't really care about the date.

Datetime was initially an object, I converted it to datetime using `pd.to.datetime`.
Now I was able to split the time to a different column, using:
`df['Time'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')`

But my problem is, the **new dtype is an object again** and for plotting reasons I think I have to convert it again in order to sort it correctly.

Final output should be the mentioned heatmap with the x-axis ranging from 06:00 AM to 23:00 AM, plotting the different actions types in two buckets on the y-axis. Just so you are aware of the final use of the data.

I'll be really thankful for any pointers for someone new to time series analysis with python pandas :)

Comment: Looks to me like the issue is on the side of whatever you're using for ploting rather than the dataframe. If your lib needs a dt object to work, obviously you can't format it however you want beforehands, your lib would have to do that.

Comment: What would you recommend to plot this as described above? I started to try it out with matplotlib and scatterplots, but I am unsure if the scatterplot is the right approach here.
Sry, quite new to this...

Comment: What is your expected output? If the time (hour) is on the x-axis, what should be on the y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a scatter chart and not a heatmap. Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%H:%M"))

ax = df.plot.scatter(x="Datetime",y="Action",rot=90)
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp("06:00"), pd.Timestamp("23:00"))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute = [0]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

###### Output:

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: why are you calling pd.to_datetime twice?

Comment: Change string to date. Change date to time (string). Change time back to date.

Comment: Right, I see, instead of apply/replace. Still, I wonder if this would work on a datetime.time axis (only floor to the minute)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Was not aware of the set.major_locator possibility, so thank you for introducing me to that.